# 555 Astable Timer: Why do these two circuits simulate differently?

Tags: timer, 555, astable

I've modeled up the following two circuits in LTSpice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwMNAx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0a56Z.png)</sup>

(I've left out the other connections for clarity, +V applied to R1, cap goes to ground, +5V and ground to the 555, output goes somewhere...)

When I simulate the first circuit in LTSPice, it tells me I'll get a peak-to-peak output frequency of ~15kHz. The second circuit, it tells me will have a frequence of ~21kHz.

If I use the typical astable 555 time calculations, they all predict 21kHz.

Why are these two circuits not behaving the same way?

EDIT: Fixed the R1 resistance - the original schematic had it different between the two circuits, and it isn't.

Comment: Why would they be the same? You added a voltage offset into the circuit when you added the diodes.

Comment: When you calculated the frequency you probably supposed ideal diodes with 0V forward voltage. But the diodes simulated are real and not ideal.

Comment: Diodes also have a finite turn on/off time which also needs to be factored in.

Comment: I assumed something about on/off times might play a role. I didn't know anything about the voltage offsets. Can I rely on LTSpice to be accurate here? If I tune this to to get the frequency perfect in LTSpice, will it probably be the same in the real world (understanding of course real world components have tolerances...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are these two circuits not behaving the same way?

the diodes: they reduce the charge-up current and the discharge current so the time to finish a cycle is longer -> lower frequency.

the effect would be bigger if you use a diode with higher Vfwd, like an led.

Comment: Hi - thanks! Can you point me at a reference that explains how I can predict/calculate this effect so I can include that factor in my design?

Answer (score 0):

This answer came prior to the question amendment that fixed R1.

They would be pretty similar except that R1 is 100 ohms in one circuit and in the other it is 1 kohm. Engineering requires precision and care.

Comment: Good point, but not with a 0.5 - 0.7 voltage offset they wouldn't, even if he DID have the same R values.

Comment: Look where the threshold pin is connected @Trevor. The capacitor will take a little longer to charge and discharge due to the added dynamic impedance of the diode but largely, it will be similar. Now go look at the two values of R1 and ask yourself if my answer deserved your down vote.

Comment: he want to know why the frequency would be different..  "The capacitor will take a little longer to charge and discharge due" = "Different Frequency". But koodos for the eagle eye on the R value.. I didn't notice that one.

Comment: So who was the downvoter if it wasn't you?

Comment: Dunno, but it's probably because your answer is incomplete. Even if he fixes the R value it wont be the same frequency.. You might want to augment it.

Comment: Yes - I made a mistake transposing the circuit into stackexchange. The circuits I simulated had the same resistance. I fixed the question.

Comment: Oh: And I didn't downvote you either! But I did upvote to try and compensate.